# Make standalone usage of command throw error after certain point in document

Tags: macros, errors

I defined a command to uniformly change sections in my document and used the \section{} command by mistake later on.

Is there a way to use \section{} in a custom command and let the usage of \section{} throw an error after defining the command?

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mysection}[2]{
    % whatever style for the entire document
    \section{#1}
    \label{#2}
}

\makeUsageOfCommandThrowErrorAfterHere{\section}

\begin{document}

\mysection{title}{label} % this should work
text

\section{another titel}{another label} % this should throw an error
more text

\end{document}
```

Comment: maybe instead of calling `\section` in `\mysection`, you can first `\let\oldsection\section` and call `\oldsection` instead in `\mysection`? Then you can redefine `\section` to something that throws the error you want.

Comment: works for me, thanks

Comment: Ah, I just saw @WillieWong's comment. My answer basically does the same.

Comment: Are you *really* sure that `\mysection{Title}{label}` is clearer and cleaner than `\section{Title}\label{label}`?

Comment: @egreg no, i am sure that "whatever style" allows me to edit the style for all the sections in the entire document in a consistent manner: color, FloatBarrier, spacings, etc. Sections and labels just happen to be a short example and I'm adding labels to each section anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply assign `\section` to something undefined, so it would throw an error when used. For example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\let\originalsection\section
\newcommand{\mysection}[2]{
    % whatever style for the entire document
    \originalsection{#1}
    \label{#2}
}
\let\section\SomethingUndefined

\begin{document}

\mysection{title}{label} % this will work
text

\section{another titel}{another label} % this will throw an error
more text

\end{document}
```

Comment: the first solution doesn't work (for me at least), the second solution works fine, like Willie Wong already commented

Comment: Ah sorry, the first solution actually doesn't work, since when `\mysection` expands to `\section`, it no longer exists. Fixed it.